# jQuery playing both HTML5 audio sources

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I'm very new to JS and jQuery.

I coded a button to toggle between playing and pausing an audio file. The problem I'm experiencing is that sometimes when I click the play button, it seems to be playing two copies of the same file. The audio is overlapping and sounds like there is a lot of reverberation.

Any ideas what might be causing this? Thanks!

```html
<button class="play"></button>

<audio class="audio-clip" preload="none">
  <source src="audio/file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="audio/file.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

```js
$('.slick-center .audio-clip').trigger('load');


$('audio.audio-clip').on('ended', function(){
    $('.slick-center button.play').removeClass('on');
});

$('button.play').toggle(
    function() {
        $('.slick-center .audio-clip').trigger('play');
        $('.slick-center button.play').addClass('on');
        return false;
    },
    function() {
        $('.slick-center .audio-clip').trigger('pause');
        $('.slick-center button.play').removeClass('on');
        return false;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was the result of using Slick Slider in infinite mode. I'm not sure exactly what the fix is if you need to keep it in infinite mode, but changing the slider to infinite:false solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your class selectors are same for both the files which makes jQuery fire them at once. Define a unique source id for each source and use id as selector in jQuery to play these files.

Comment: There is only one audio element in OP's code, source elements can't be fired.

Comment: @ kaiido Audio tag contains two source elements and he's using the same selector class to fire "play"  shared by these audio sources. $('.slick-center .audio-clip').trigger('play'); . That's why two audio files are getting played at the same time.

Comment: no, `.audio-clip` class is only applied onto the `<audio>` element, and it's not possible to call play from a `<source>` element anyway. `<audio>` element has this method, but it should pick the first source it is able to read. In no way it should play multiple files at the same time. Either this is a really odd bug, either something else is happening and OP is hiding it to us.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var playing = false;

$('.play').click(function() {
    playing = !playing;
    $('.play').toggleClass('on');
    if (playing) {
        $('.audio-clip').trigger('play');
    }
    else {
        $('.audio-clip').trigger('pause');
    }
});
```

I recommend using a library like [howler.js](http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library) or [Buzz](http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/) for audio playback. These are simple to use and solve cross-browser issues.

Comment: Thanks, @pulse I like that solution better than mine. Unfortunately, it has fixed the problem of the audio file echoing. There's a staging version of the site up at alicepringle.staging.wpengine.com if you wanna take a look.